# Javascript substring check

Tags: javascript, html, string, compare

I am working with images, they all have their sizes mentioned in their name tag.

```
 http://mysite.com/audio/display%20image/130x130%20jpeg/5755285.jpg
```

I am getting those is an array of strings. I need to check if the string contains the size 
`130x130` in it. How can it be done?

Comment: `string.indexOf("130x130") > -1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = 'http://mysite.com/audio/display%20image/130x130%20jpeg/5755285.jpg';
var search = '130x130';

str.indexOf(search);
```

If it returns anything but -1 the string has been found:

```
if (str.indexOf(search) > -1) {
    // Your image contains 130x130
} else {
    // Your image does not contains 130x130
}
```